# Need some help recovering a hacked Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, security

I've been unfortunate enough to be on the receiving end of a hack on my website. According to the webhost, the hack created multiple email accounts for the purposes of sending spam email.

I am fairly confident that the cPanel password was not compromised as I use a unique one that contains gibberish.

Please do have a quick look at the following malware scan and do let me know if anyone is able to identify the cause of the hack so that I may update or remove the plugin in question:

> FILE HIT LIST: {HEX}php.generic.malware.444 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/akismet.php.19219493 {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/qtwckryc.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/qtwckryc.php.210$ {HEX}php.base64.v23au.186 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-content/cache/tmp/favicon_0d59b4.ico
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/favicon_0d59b4.ico.96$ {HEX}gzbase64.inject.unclassed.15 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-post.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/wp-post.php.1750329931
>   {HEX}gzbase64.inject.unclassed.15 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-post.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/wp-post.php.223812868
>   {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/nkwpabqu.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/nkwpabqu.php.686111002
>   {HEX}php.generic.malware.444 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/content-large.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/conte$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 : /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/menu.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/menu.php.321404278
>   {HEX}php.nested.base64.563 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/.qidb/sma.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/sma.php.2032931861
>   {HEX}php.nested.base64.563 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/.qidb/ini_slide-menues.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/ini_slide-menues.php.28531$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.444 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/class-phpmailer.php.230442$
>   {HEX}php.generic.malware.444 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/class-wp-ima$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.444 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/FilteredIterator.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/Filtered$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/wp-includes/certificates/bikkduoa.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/bi$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 : /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/wp-includes/images/smilies/tjrrepex.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 : /home/**removed**/public_html/**removed**/gallery.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/gallery.php.491312761
>   {HEX}php.nested.base64.563 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/.well-known/pki-validation/ini_db_model.php
>   => /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/ini_db_model.php$ {HEX}php.generic.malware.442 :
>   /home/**removed**/public_html/wp-admin/user/bwztkznu.php =>
>   /usr/local/maldetect/quarantine/bwztkznu.php.682430871

Thank you very much for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

from those logs it wouldnt be possible to work out the cause of the hack, it could have been a simple password brute force attack or XSS vulnerabilities - but here are some best practices that will make it harder to hack in the future:

1. Remove all affected files and false email accounts (this looks like its already done)
2. Make sure all plugins and wordpress is up to latest version
3. [Install Better WP Security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) - follow the setup wizard